# Why won't my jQuery validation code work when run in the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

It works in jsfiddle. I don't understand why it won't work when I run it in the browser. The only thing I can think of is I might have linked the jquery file incorrectly / linked the wrong one. I have tried many though. Basically I went on the jquery site, downloaded jquery, linked it (it's in the same folder). I also tried the specific validation, didn't work. Now I'm using the link that worked in jsfiddle. Please help. :(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>
      <head>
         <title>JQ</title>

             <script src="validate.js"></script>
             <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

     </head>
     <body>
             <form id="signupform">Username
             <input id="user" name="user" type="text" />
        <br/>
             <button type="submit">Submit</button>
             </form>

    </body>
 </html>
```

This is my JS code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#signupform").validate({
    rules: {
        user: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4
        }
    },
    messages: {
        user: {
            required: "please enter a username",
            minlength: "Your username must be at least 4 characters long"
        }
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the jQuery library

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>
      <head>
         <title>JQ</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script><!--Include jQuery before includign the plugin-->
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="validate.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
             <form id="signupform">Username
             <input id="user" name="user" type="text" />
        <br/>
             <button type="submit">Submit</button>
             </form>

    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Ah your edited code works now, thank you! I thought I had them in the right order, guess not. But thanks I was frustrated over this for ages but the fix was so simple.